# Is it possible to plug in and out sensors, LED-s etc. on the breadboard while the Raspberry is running?

Tags: gpio, breadboard, voltage

What I would like to do, is to let the Raspberry Pi run and while it is running, connect and disconnect eg. sensors whenever I please to/from the breadboard WITHOUT turning off/disconnecting the Pi from the breadboard.

As far as I know, there could be trouble because of the unregular voltage and in the worst case, the Pi would get killed.
Is there a piece of hardware which enables me to do so? I have heard about giving an external source of electricity for the breadboard but I am looking for something different, something more "mobile".

Comment: I reconnect things all the time while its running, never had an issue. BUT the reason why you SHOULD turn it off is because if you make a mistake by accidentally creating a short or something you don't have to correct the mistake before you turn the pi back on. Plus if code running on the pi is accessing the GPIO and you mess with it, it could cause weird behavior.   But if its just an led that your taking in and out, I wouldn't expect there to be a problem.

Comment: As I said, it should be sensors and actuators not only leds. And yes, the code running on the pi is accessing the GPIO

Comment: Then your code needs to be able to handle the hot swap. It needs to be able to reset/configure the device when it becomes present again.  And not crash or do bad things when the sensor gets taken away.  I realize thats broad, but it really depends on what type of sensor and what the data is being used for.  Or i guess you just said you dont want to turn the pi off, but maybe you will have stopped the program, in which case it gets a little easier.

Comment: The problem is that it should work for any kind of sensors and actuators...

Comment: then you have to design your code to handle hot swapping of any type of sensor. Some sensors require certain setup procedures, or certain amount of up time before they are reliable, so you will have to code for those possible issues.

Comment: What do you have in mind? Could you please give an example?

Comment: again it depends on the sensor, some sensors need certain initialization steps to make them function correctly. and you also have to be able to identify when the device was removed and when it was put back in place. Which will also vary based on the sensor.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot tell what sensors are going to connected to the pi. So my best option is to hard-code solutions to each and every sensor which ever existed?

Comment: Well the best option would be to know what type of sensors your going to use. Beyond that, look at how devices are handled in mainstream computer stuff. Every computer has output for sound/video, and input for mouse/keyboard ect, then a driver is build to bridge the two devices. It would not make sense for the OS to know how to talk to every device out of the box, many drivers are included, but many also get added later.  You could use the same idea and build a driver for every new type of sensor you use, that bridges the new sensor with the existing program.